# Select value to var in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In Angular.js - How to check the value of the selected option on a Dropdown?

I have a dropdown menu, and a plus button next to it.

When the button is pressed a function triggers. How do I get "selected" into a var?

({{selected}} works in html, but I want this value in JS)

```
>  <select ng-options="key as key for (key, prop) in
> vm.schema.properties" ng-model="selected"">
>     </select>  //the dropdown


<p id="plusbutton">  //the add button
<div class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-model="selected" ng-click="vm.addMappingField()">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
</div>
</p>
```

Javascript/Angular:

```
    function addMappingField() {

       var item = {{selected}}; //Here should be the value of the dropdown

        vm.mappingFields.push({
            destination: "item",
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass selected model as paramter of addMappingField function or you can access it directly in controller like `$scope.selected`

```
<div class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="vm.addMappingField(selected)">


function addMappingField(selected) {

   var item = selected //Here should be the value of the dropdown

    vm.mappingFields.push({
        destination: "item",
    });
};
```

Comment: that comes out as "selected undefined"

Comment: Nevermind i fixed it! thank you. 

I tried this already but i guess i got the syntax wrong or double defined something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of, you are setting the `selected` as the NgModel on two different elements, it should only be set on the select tag.

Secondly, connect the selected model to the vm and then just refere it in the addMappingField() method in the controller

View

```
<select ng-options="key as key for (key, prop) in vm.schema.properties" ng-model="vm.selected"">
</select> 

<p id="plusbutton">
    <div class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="vm.addMappingField()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </div>
</p>
```

Controller

```
function addMappingField() {

   var item = vm.selected;

    vm.mappingFields.push({
        destination: "item",
    });
};
```

Comment: just add "vm.selected = selected;"  to the vm?

Comment: @SNT As the vm already is defined, you don't need to set the vm.selected yourself. the ng-model will set the value to the selected option

Comment: I understand, thank you Sir. both answers work but i suppose using vm in stead of scope would be a better way to go

Comment: @SNT Np, yepp. Either use scope or vm. dont mix the two :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove *ng-model="selected"* in the dom. 
`<div class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="vm.addMappingField()">`

If your using scope as vm makes sure these changes in your code.

```
 function addMappingField() {

   var item = vm.selected //Here should be the value of the dropdown

    vm.mappingFields.push({
        destination: item,
    });
};
```

OR if using `$scope` in your controller change to

```
var item = $scope.selected
```